# Product Listing Page Using Same Image for more than one product

Tags: php

Problem - a web page showcases a number of products some of which use the same image.

Question - To improve page loading speed I want to use one image for each product requiring the same image.

As a very amateur PHPer I have considered loading the image into an array as the script loops through the database output and when a duplicate image is found it uses the first instance of the image rather than a new version - so far my attempts have failed !

Is this approach in the right direction ? - any assistance, pointers much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're talking of very very high numbers of images, working on the server-side loading of those images will lead you close to nowhere.

Presuming you only get an image url from your DB (and not the full image stream) using the same url in the generated HTML will be enough to allow the browsers to download it just once and cache it for future uses (aka not downloading it twice)

P.S.: If I presumed wrong please update your question specifying HOW you're loading/using those images

Comment: Thanks for your reply - Yes, I do get just the URL from db and although some images are the same (they are provisioned by affiliate) the name I have assigned them refers to the product name and therefore you potentially have product A that is size 6x3 and product B that is size 8x6 and both share the same image although the image albeit with a different name. I am trying to use thew same image (URL) for both products. Hope that helps clarify my goal ?

Comment: You can try using http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-file.php to generate an hash of the image and then replace all the duplicates with the first url with that hash (hash_file() supports also urls)

Answer (score 0):

OK, with the help of the above answers I appear to have found a solution to my problem using the following code (it may not be the best or quickest way of achieving the desired result, but it does work !)  :

```
    <?php
    $image=array();  // create array outside of loop

    // START loop

    while (!$rsRESULTS->EOF) { 

    $src="url-of-image";

    $imageFile= file_get_contents($src) ; // make image into a file

    if(in_array($imageFile,$image)){ // check if file is already in array

    $imageID= array_search ($imageFile,$image); // if yes, then get the key from the        matching value

    $src="http://www.log-cabin.co/_images/affiliates/shedstore/".$imageID.".jpg";

    }else{
    $key=$rsRESULTS->Fields('id'); // set up key using unique identifier
    $image[$key]=$imageFile; // if not already in array add file to array using file name as key
    }

    // SHOW PRODUCT RESULTS INCLUDING PICTURE HERE
    // END loop
    $rsRESULTS->MoveNext(); 
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

2 Tables - media_to_product and media, multiple products can have the same media_id. The browser should only load once and cache on the front end.

**media_to_product**

product_id, media_id

**media**

id,filename

Comment: That won't help in this case because each product will have a different name and therefore the image, although the same as others will also have a different name.

Comment: If you save the image and use a new table something like image_to_product and a media table. you can save the media tables unique id to a product in the image_to_product table. That way a product can also have multiple images and share images.